# Location is null on older Android versions(API 21) but it works fine on newer ones (API 25)

Tags: android, geolocation, location, google-play-services

mLastLocation is null when tested on API level 21 but that is not the case on API level 25.

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        checkInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    // Permission is not granted

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);


                }

                else {
                    createLocationRequest();
                    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                    if (mLastLocation == null) {
                        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, MainActivity.this);
                    } else {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy");
                        String checkInDate = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

                        DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("h: mm a");
                        String checkInTime = df1.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

                        final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber())
                                .child("Check_in")
                                .child(checkInDate).child(checkInTime);


                        latValue = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                        longValue = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());


                        String address = getCompleteAddressString(Double.parseDouble(latValue), Double.parseDouble(longValue));

                        ref.child("Latitude").setValue(latValue).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    ref.child("Longitude").setValue(longValue).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
                                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                                                editor.putBoolean("isCheckedIn", true).apply();


                                                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                                        .make(coordinatorLayoutMainActivity, "Check-in successful !", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

                                                View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                                                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green));

                                                TextView tv = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                                tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.snackbar_text_size));

                                                snackbar.show();


                                                checkInBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                checkOutBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            } else {
                                                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                                        .make(coordinatorLayoutMainActivity, "Please try again.", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

                                                View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                                                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));

                                                TextView tv = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                                tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.snackbar_text_size));

                                                snackbar.show();
                                            }
                                        }

                                    });
                                } else {
                                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                            .make(coordinatorLayoutMainActivity, "Please try again.", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

                                    View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                                    snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));

                                    TextView tv = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.snackbar_text_size));

                                    snackbar.show();
                                }

                            }
                        });


                        ref.child("Address").setValue(address);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

@SuppressLint({"RestrictedApi", "MissingPermission"})
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    //remove location updates so that it resets
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this); //Import should not be **android.Location.LocationListener**
    //import should be **import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener**;

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    //restart location updates with the new interval
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

}

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission was granted
                // Do the contacts-related task you need to do.

                createLocationRequest();
                mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            } else {
                // permission denied. Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.

                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayoutMainActivity, "You need to allow access to location.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));

                TextView tv = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.snackbar_text_size_18sp));

                snackbar.show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request.
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}
```

What I am trying to do is to get the user's location when they press a button.

Its working as expected on Android Nougat (asking for runtime permission and then working fine) but not on Android Lollipop (there's no concept of runtime permission in versions older than Marshmallow).

What could be the problem?